# Validate DateTime value in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On an ASP.NET MVC 5.2 project I have a model with a DateTime? property:

```
public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
```

And on the view I have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Birthday, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")
```

When I submit it with an invalid date I get the error:

```
The value '123' is not valid for Birthday.
```

I would like to change this message but not able with Fluent Validation which I use.

I think this message is added to ModelStater errors maybe in a model binder?

I was looking for it on MVC source but couldn't find it ...

Could someone tell me how to override this?

Comment: you can add required attribute to Birthday property and on the view add `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Birthday)`

Comment: What do you mean? What I need is to change the error message text when the user inserts an invalid date ... If the user inserts a null then I can accept it because I do not require that the date is filled

Comment: please, see my edited answer below

Answer (score 0):

to avoid of submitting invalid date, you can add client validation:

**View:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Birthday, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Birthday)
```

**Model:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is wrong")]
public DateTime? Birthday { get; set; }
```

if you have not client validation, this error will be in ModelState

in case if you do not want validation, you can:

1) Remove an error from ModealState by key "Birthday"

2) Set `Birthday` property as string `public string Birthday { get; set; }`, add custom jQuery validation, parse this one on the server

anyway required date or no, model binder binds datetime due to server localization, and will add in modelstate error if binding was failed

Comment: I think I will go for the string option ... I would to avoid attributes since I am using Fluent Validation

Comment: good, I think there is nothing bad in using string and custom jquery validation

Answer (score 0):

Correct it gets place in model state by the default model binder.

These messages can be customized by defining them in a Resource file and then assigning the name of the resource file into the static string property ResourceClassKey of the class DefaultModelBinder. The Implicit Required Field custom error message has to be put under a key named DefaultModelBinder_ValueRequired and the Wrong Format custom error message under a key named DefaultModelBinder_ValueInvalid. While the Implicit Required Field custom error message is used on both client side and server side the Wrong Format custom error message is used just on the server side.

The message has two “holes” {0} is for the value and {1} for the DisplayName of the field. The standard message for the English is: The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.

A good place where to assign a value to the ResourceClassKey property is the global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{ 
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); 
    DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "MyResources"; 
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters); 
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); 
}
```

http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2012/01/17/Customizing-Error-Messages-in-AspNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: The problem is that I am not using Resource Files for localization but a custom system that relies on POT files